# TestNG's @Test annotation at class level will execute groovy synthetic methods as well

Tags: java, groovy, testng

I'm having a groovy class with TestNG's @Test annotation at class level just like this:

```
@Test(groups = [ 'testGroup' ])
public class PageCountEngagementMetricTest {

   @Test
   public void pageCountEngagementMetricTest() {
      println('hello')
   }
}
```

After the executing of this test class I get the groovy's synthetic methods executed as well. I'm using groovy-1.8.5 and testng-6.8, is there a way to tell TestNG/Groovy to not execute synthetic methods ?

Not using the @Test annotation at class level will solve this problem but it is not very convenient as I have to specify the groups for every test method.